# Anyway to upload file by ajax in JSF?

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I need to upload file ajax so that I can show the name of uploaded file but without adding any jar files like primefaces, richfaces.

My form is inside dialog box where I have an upload button which should call a method by ajax. My code is something like this...

```
<h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{bean.uploadMethod}">
<f:ajax listener="#{bean.abcMethod}" event="click"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

and I would also like to know if I can just browse, keep the name of file in some list to show and then I can submit my whole form. This submission should also upload those files which I have shown the name in list. Is it possible?

Comment: [Coming soon in JSF 2.2](http://java.net/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&requestId=11471). We're patiently waiting

Answer (score 2):

I'm also struggling with uploading files (images) through AJAX. I've looked for several methods and how companies like Google or Dropbox implemented this.

So far I found two methods:

- Use an `iframe` to submit the file. This isn't actually AJAX, so it works in most browsers. However I have yet to see an implementation (other than PrimeFaces') in JSF.
- Encode the file client side with base64, send through AJAX and decode on the server side. However I haven't seen an implementation in JSF and I haven't got the time past days to actually cook something up.

If you want a quick solution you can use [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces), [richfaces](/questions/tagged/richfaces) (and probably [icefaces](/questions/tagged/icefaces)). But you already said you didn't want to use one of those.

Maybe someone is nice enough to post a real solution here, but I thought I'd throw in an idea or two. ;-)

Comment: See my answer if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces offers the FileUpload component which is a fully AJAX enabled file upload JSF component.

[Here is the showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf)

I am not complete sure how it works but I believe it utilizes modern browser features through HTML5.  This functionality of course requires that the client be a modern browser that can understand HTML5 markup.

Comment: IIRC the component uses HTML5 on modern browsers but can fall back on the iframe method on older browsers.

Comment: @siebz0r It can be set to `simple` mode for browsers that are not compatible with HTML5 however this is a markup setting.  I do not believe it uses iframes in this scenario, I believe it non-AJAX enabled standard browser level file upload control.